# Adding a action listener to a jbutton

Tags: java, button

To start off, I'm not an experienced programmer or anything of the sort, I'm trying to make a simple java button and a text to tell you how many times you've pressed said button, here's the code so far:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;


public class cookieClicker {
private static void cookies() {
    int a = 0;
    JFrame cookie = new JFrame("Cookie Counter");
    cookie.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JButton clickCookies = new JButton("Cookies!!");
    clickCookies.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
        a++;
    } 

    } );


    if ( a == 0 ) {
        JLabel text1 = new JLabel("You have no cookies you fat twat!", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        text1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 150));
        cookie.getContentPane().add(text1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }
    else {
    if ( a == 1 ) {
        JLabel text2 = new JLabel("You have " + a + " cookie", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        text2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 150));
        cookie.getContentPane().add(text2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    else {
        JLabel text3 = new JLabel("You have " + a + " cookies", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        text3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 150));
        cookie.getContentPane().add(text3, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    }
    clickCookies.setBounds(50,100,95,30);
    cookie.add(clickCookies);
    cookie.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    cookie.setLayout(new FlowLayout() );
    cookie.pack();
    cookie.setVisible(true);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

cookies();

}
}
```

When compiling it gives back:

```
cookieClicker.java:15: error: local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final
a++;
^
```

Comment: Avoid the over use of `static`, `a` needs to be moved outside of the local context (as making it final would prevent you from updating it). You could move `a` into the context of the `ActionListener`

Comment: All the functionality relating to adding the labels, should be done within the `ActionListener`

Comment: Also have a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: @Eugene. That's terrible advice. There's a reason that sort of behavior causes an error.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your question: you need to store the count (a) in a field, not in a local variable.

But your code shows a big misunderstanding of the principle of events and listeners. You're trying to get the number of clicks immediately after you've created your JFrame, and even before you've made it visible. That makes no sense. How could the user have clicked on the button at that time? You need to change the text of your label (instead of adding a new label every time), from the listener itself: when the button is clicked, the displayed text changes. That's the role of the actionPerformed method: react to a button click.

The offical [Swing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) has plenty of examples and explanations showing

- how to start an application
- how to use a class representing your JFrame, and not do anything in static methods
- how to use listeners
- how to layout components

Read them, because you're really not doing things in a goood way.